# Databound controls with null value being rendered

Tags: asp.net, controls, databound, databound-controls

Although I'm a huge fan of Databound controls since ASP.Net 2.0 and have been using them a lot since learning them, I seem to have stumbled upon an unnoticed(or rather not cared about) issue that these controls seem to have.

I'm using ASP.Net 3.5 and the issue that I noticed is that when using Databound controls(such as Labels, HyperLinks) inside a Data-Control(such as Datalist, Gridview etc.), even if the value returned for one column is `NULL`, it is still rendered albeit as an empty tag.

For eg: I have a `Datalist` in which I have a `Label` whose value may or may not be `NULL`. Now there's no problem when the value is not `NULL`, the problem is when the value is `NULL`. Ideally, no HTML should be rendered for a controls that don't have any value, but in this case, the HTML(`<span></span>` in case of the Label) of the corresponding `NULL` valued control is still being rendered.

Now, as I said earlier that most people won't care about this as it isn't much of an issue, but if you consider the fact that this control may be enclosed in a hierarchy of parent controls, and then repeated many a times, this could significantly increase the HTML content(since the ID of your HTML content is based on the parent controls) without any Text added to maintain the Text/HTML ratio, thereby becoming a cause for the Search Engines to shy away from indexing your pages fully.

I couldn't find anything related to this matter anywhere else so I thought to bring it up here. Is this really an issue with databound controls or am I missing something here?

Help is always appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, that makes sense because control's don't auto hide themselves, you'd have to explicitly hide them through Visible="False", even with no content.  This is consistent with the databound controls and non-databound controls alike.  Excluding the markup when no content is there could potentially be chaotic to an application, especially if the page used JavaScript.

HTH.

Comment: Firstly, thanks for the reply. Well, here's a question out of lack of knowledge - I haven't worked with ASP.Net 4.0 and just heard about dynamic controls, can these dynamic controls help solve this issue?

Comment: Another thing, when we put `Visible = "false";` that HTML is not rendered but still the server knows about it, so, at server side there shouldn't be any problem if the HTML is not rendered here. Regarding Client side, the problems that may arise would also arise if we hide the control using `Visible = "false";` so I guess the point I made is still valid.